# Converting Future to string flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to convert the response from api to string in flutter. I am still a beginner to Flutter so I'm sorry about that.
Whenever I do the get and assign it to a variable, the value is always 'Instance of Future' rather than the actual text? So does this mean I have to convert it to text?
This is the code that I used.

```
gethttps() async{
  var response = await http.get(url);

  print("JSON" + response.body);

  String data = response.body;
  data = json.decode(response.body.toString());
  return data;
}
```

CALL FROM OUTSIDE THE FUNCTION

var response = gethttps();

Answer (score 1):

you can follow the link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50296350/6413387

Basically you have two options

```
gethttps().then((result) {
  print(result);
  setState(() {
    someVal = result;
  })
})
```

or

```
funcThatMakesAsyncCall() async {
  String result = await gethttps();
  print(result);  
  setState(() {
    someVal = result;
  })
}
```

Comment: for some reason the setState doesn't seem to be working, it has red line underneath?

Comment: that means your widget is stateless widget

Answer (score 0):

You can change signature of function to this one

```
Future<String> gethttps() async{....}
```

and then use

```
var data=await gethttps();
```

user await

Comment: `ListView createArticleButtons() async {
  var response = await gethttps();`

It shows an error on the ListView. How can I fix it please?

Comment: yeah, you can use FutureBuilder